# Flutter Assigning QuerySnapshot to Map<dynamic, dynamic>

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch some menu item details such as menu name, slogan text icon, and verify data from firebase firestore using flutter but in the services of database getMenus() function, I am facing an error.

I have the following class model

```
import 'dart:convert';

MenuModel medicalTestModelFromJson(String str) => MenuModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));
String medicalTestModelToJson(MenuModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class MenuModel {
  MenuModel({
    required this.title,
    required this.slogan,
    required this.icon,
    required this.verify,
  });

  String title;
  String slogan;
  String icon;
  bool verify;

  factory MenuModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MenuModel(
    title: json["title"],
    slogan: json["slogan"],
    icon: json["icon"],
    verify: json["verify"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "title": title,
    "slogan": slogan,
    "icon": icon,
    "verify": verify,
  };
}
```

And the following is the menu collection services from firebase firestore

```
class MenuServices{

  static Future<List<MenuModel>> getMenus() async {
    QuerySnapshot menuSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('homeItems').where("verify", isEqualTo: true).get();
    List<MenuModel> menus =[];
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = menuSnapshot.docs; //(***My Error is Exactly in this line which menuSnapshot.docs is not recognizing***)
    values.forEach((key, values) {
      menus.add(MenuModel.fromJson(values));
    });
    return menus;
  }
}
```

And the error is

```
A value of type 'List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
class MenuServices{

  static Future<List<MenuModel>> getMenus() async {
    QuerySnapshot menuSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('homeItems').where("verify", isEqualTo: true).get();

    List<MenuModel> menus = menuSnapshot.docs.map(
    (e)=> MenuModel.fromJson(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList();
   
    return menus;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I bring changes based on your suggestion but now I have another error exactly in (e.data()) and the error is 

The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked:

```
void getLeituras(QuerySnapshot snapshot){

    List leituras = [];
    Leitura leitura;
    snapshot.docs.forEach((e) {
      leitura = Leitura();
      leitura = Leitura.fromJson(e.data as Map<String, dynamic>);
      leituras.add(leitura);

    });  
}
```